# jquery.cookies.js - Is it possible to set expiration time to the bound cookies with input field?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have many input fields that I bind with a cookie for each of them using `$('input[id^="_val"]').cookieBind({path: '/path', expiresAt: new Date(time_in_milli)});`. It binds the cookie with the input field for all input fiels starting with the value `_val` and set them with path `/path` but it doesn't set them with the expiration time.

I am using the [cookies](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/wiki/Documentation) plugin and jquery 1.5.

Could someone suggest me how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

instead of expiresAt: try expires:, I use it all time without issues.

Comment: did you mean that you use `expires` with http://code.google.com/p/cookies/wiki/Documentation plugin?